# How to load and save a textboxe value to the app config file at runtime

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I working on an integrated test application, in this application we have to generate a customer account number.now this account number has to be saved in a app config file at run time, however when you run the application again the config file has to be loaded and get the last value saved and continue from there. so far this is what I have done , any help will be welcome

```
 //Clear the text box
IWebElement UPC = _driver.FindElement(By.Id("Details_tbxaccount")); 
//load the configuration file string 
bool IsValid = false; 
int start = 1; 
MyId = null; 
IWebElement UPCTxt ; 
while (!IsValid) 
{ 
     UPC.Clear(); 
     MyId = start.ToString().PadLeft(13,'0'); 
     UPCTxt =_driver.FindElement(By.Id("Details_tbxaccount"));  
     UPCTxt.SendKeys(MyId); 
     if (_driver.FindElement(By.Id("UniqueMessage")).Text.Contains("The Account Number you have entered already exists")) 
     { 
         start++; 
     } 
     else 
     {
         IsValid = true; 
     } 
 } //save the configuration file
```